# a non-constant entire function example

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to find an example of a non-constant entire function $f$ such that $sup_{x}|f(x)|+sup_{y} |f(iy)|< \infty$

Is $f(z)= e^{sin (z)}$ satisfy the condition since $|f(x)|=|e^{sin(x)}|≤e$ and $|f(iy)|=|e^ {i sinh(y) }|=1$ and so $sup_{x}|f(x)|+sup_{y} |f(iy)|< \infty$ ?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your example works.

Comment: $e^{-z^4}$ is another one that works